# Having Just one root

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For which values of $k$ the equation $3x^3+5x\sqrt{x}+k^2-1=0$ has just one root?

1. $k>\sqrt{2}$
2. $k\neq 1,-1$
3. $|k|>1$
4. $|k|<1$

I think 4 is the right choice.

Comment: ...one real root, right? Why are you confident with 4)? Could you please add some details to your question, explaining your computations? :)

Comment: Why do you think 4 is the right choice? Can you give us a few more details please?

Comment: Are choices 3 and 4 supposed to be identical?

Comment: @Avitus: 4 and 3 are the same. Typo!!

Comment: @Adriano: Sorry. I'll fix it

Comment: @Avitus: I don't have any other conditions or information. I am told that is right.

Comment: Substitute $x\sqrt{x}\mapsto y$ and analyse the resulting quadratic equation.

Comment: @Basil R, ok, but then can you find the roots of a degree 3 polynomial? Does the word "discriminant" tell you anything? If not, please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function under "The nature of the roots" to get a first idea.

Comment: @Avitus: I'll do that. I am trying the Eckhard's hint.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x)=3x^3+5x\sqrt{x}$ whose domain must be $[0,\infty)$. Observe that its derivative is positive for all $x>0$ so that the function is monotonically increasing. Hence, its global min occurs at $x=0$, which yields a minimum of $f(0)=0$. Draw a rough sketch of the curve using this information. Notice that vertically translating $f(x)$ upwards would make the resulting curve no longer intersect the $x$-axis, whereas leaving $f(x)$ alone or vertically translating $f(x)$ downwards would make the resulting curve continue to intersect the $x$-axis only once.

Hence, the equation $f(x) + C=0$ has just one real root iff $C\le0$. Substituting $C=k^2-1$ and solving for $k$ yields $|k|\le1$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
                  3x³ +5x√x +k²-1 =f(x)
```

the equation is defined only for X >=0, as a √X appears in the question.

when x=0,  we find k²=1,  Also (3x³+5x√x) ≥0 for all X≥0,

thereefore to attain a zero the constant term should be negative.

hence,   k²-1 <0, OR THE ANSWER IS 4